# how to center typed js on the screen

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have typing animation and I am trying to make it center both horizontaly and vertically. Here is my attempt so far:

```js
$(function(){
 $(".text").typed({
  strings: ["Lepson mosa losha ohyao", "Zin oh mosa lofoa kosha doa arosma notna loffshi", "Corsa tosm smflos slsfjs zofa ora toshsa lofasoz zohmrah cormasos asrsaos lofma toshm cerokc lsosa formas kaks in tososh fojus alsoma"],
  // Optionally use an HTML element to grab strings from (must wrap each string in a <p>)
  stringsElement: null,
  // typing speed
  typeSpeed: 30,
  // time before typing starts
  startDelay: 1200,
  // backspacing speed
  backSpeed: 20,
  // time before backspacing
  backDelay: 500,
  // loop
  loop: true,
  // false = infinite
  loopCount: 15,
  // show cursor
  showCursor: false,
  // character for cursor
  cursorChar: "|",
  // attribute to type (null == text)
  attr: null,
  // either html or text
  contentType: 'html',
  // call when done callback function
  callback: function() {},
  // starting callback function before each string
  preStringTyped: function() {},
  //callback for every typed string
  onStringTyped: function() {},
  // callback for reset
  resetCallback: function() {}
 });
});
```

```css
.text{
position: absolute;
left: 120px;
top: 100px;

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/typed.js/1.1.1/typed.min.js"></script>
        

<h1> <span class="text"></span></h1>
```

I am trying to make the change on css but it does not look good so ar

Comment: *"... center both horizontaly and vertically..."* into **what**?

Comment: Or you could simply Google: "center both horizontally and vertically css" and the first result would give you: https://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```css
h1 {
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```js
$(function(){
 $(".text").typed({
  strings: ["Lepson mosa losha ohyao", "Zin oh mosa lofoa kosha doa arosma notna loffshi", "Corsa tosm smflos slsfjs zofa ora toshsa lofasoz zohmrah cormasos asrsaos lofma toshm cerokc lsosa formas kaks in tososh fojus alsoma"],
  // Optionally use an HTML element to grab strings from (must wrap each string in a <p>)
  stringsElement: null,
  // typing speed
  typeSpeed: 30,
  // time before typing starts
  startDelay: 1200,
  // backspacing speed
  backSpeed: 20,
  // time before backspacing
  backDelay: 500,
  // loop
  loop: true,
  // false = infinite
  loopCount: 15,
  // show cursor
  showCursor: false,
  // character for cursor
  cursorChar: "|",
  // attribute to type (null == text)
  attr: null,
  // either html or text
  contentType: 'html',
  // call when done callback function
  callback: function() {},
  // starting callback function before each string
  preStringTyped: function() {},
  //callback for every typed string
  onStringTyped: function() {},
  // callback for reset
  resetCallback: function() {}
 });
});
```

```css
h1 {
  min-height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;                /* optional: */
  padding: 50px;            /* optional: */
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  margin: 0;                /* needed on SO */
}
.text {
  border: 1px solid red;    /* not needed */
  padding: 1rem;            /* not needed */
  text-align: center;       /* optional!? */
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/typed.js/1.1.1/typed.min.js"></script>

<h1><span class="text"></span></h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap `span` tag with center pinner.

Try following:

```js
$(function(){
 $(".text").typed({
  strings: ["Lepson mosa losha ohyao", "Zin oh mosa lofoa kosha doa arosma notna loffshi", "Corsa tosm smflos slsfjs zofa ora toshsa lofasoz zohmrah cormasos asrsaos lofma toshm cerokc lsosa formas kaks in tososh fojus alsoma"],
  // Optionally use an HTML element to grab strings from (must wrap each string in a <p>)
  stringsElement: null,
  // typing speed
  typeSpeed: 30,
  // time before typing starts
  startDelay: 1200,
  // backspacing speed
  backSpeed: 20,
  // time before backspacing
  backDelay: 500,
  // loop
  loop: true,
  // false = infinite
  loopCount: 15,
  // show cursor
  showCursor: false,
  // character for cursor
  cursorChar: "|",
  // attribute to type (null == text)
  attr: null,
  // either html or text
  contentType: 'html',
  // call when done callback function
  callback: function() {},
  // starting callback function before each string
  preStringTyped: function() {},
  //callback for every typed string
  onStringTyped: function() {},
  // callback for reset
  resetCallback: function() {}
 });
});
```

```css
.box {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate( -50%, -50% );
  width: 100vw;
}

.text {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate( -50%, -50% );

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/typed.js/1.1.1/typed.min.js"></script>
        

<h1> <div class="box"><span class="text"></span></div></h1>
```

Comment: When your centered element is taller than the parent, you can no longer scroll to its start. See [this example](https://jsfiddle.net/websiter/j6f6urmu/).